# How to both constrain an Array and signal protocol implementation

Tags: arrays, swift, protocols

You indicate that an extension implements a protocol using the syntax:

```
extension Array : MyProtocol
```

You can constrain an Array extension using the syntax:

```
extension Array where Element:MyProtocol
```

I have a situation where I want to indicate that MyProtocol is implemented for Arrays only where Element implements MyProtocol, so I tried:

```
extension Array where Element:MyProtocol : MyProtocol {
}
```

which gives a horribly obscure error message

```
Statement cannot begin with a closure expression
```

and:

```
extension Array : MyProtocol where Element:MyProtocol {
}
```

here the error message is somewhat clearer:

```
Extension of type 'Array' with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause
```

How can I implement a protocol on an array only if the elements also implement the protocol?  The last error message seems to indicate that I'm SOL.  Thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: That is – as far as I know – not possible with the current Swift. That is also the reason why arrays of Equatable elements do not conform to Equatable. See for example this discussion in the Apple Developer Forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7172.

Comment: Yeah, I pretty much assumed that was the answer, just trying to verify it.